# Unity3D - Rotating object towards point and rolling

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i've got a gameobject, which moves straight ahead and can turn left, right, up and down using this function:

```
void moveTowardsPoint(Vector3 targetPoint)
{
    //forward movement
    var movementSpeed = Time.deltaTime * speed;
    transform.position += transform.forward * movementSpeed;

    //rotation
    Vector3 dir = targetPoint - transform.position;
    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(dir);
    var turnSpeed = Time.deltaTime * 2f;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, turnSpeed);
}
```

i want to make this object roll, proportionally to how much it turns left or right. for 20° turn, i want to roll by 20° aswell (angles relative to my startangle)

would actually be even nicer, if i can set a roll limit and it would turn lets say by 30° and roll by 15°.

Here is a topdown view of how this behaviour looks like:

[image]

Comment: could you make an image of how this roll behavior would work? for both cases.

Comment: here is an image of what im trying to make it look like. think of it like how a plane would turn